# Write a void (non-fruitful) function to draw a square. Use it in a program to draw the image shown below. Assume each side is 20 units

Tags: python, python-turtle

Write a void (non-fruitful) function to draw a square. Use it in a program to draw the image shown below.
Assume each side is 20 units. (Hint: notice that the turtle has already moved away from the ending point of the
last square when the program ends.)

I am required to draw as such:

[image]

Here is the sample of my code

```
import turtle
def draw_square(t, sz):
    """Get turtle t to draw a square with sz side"""

    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(sz)
        t.left(90)


def main():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("white")

    alex = turtle.Turtle()
    alex.color("Blue")

    draw_square(alex, 20)

    wn.exitonclick()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem and what you did try before posting. Some examples of inputs and expected outputs are always useful. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I programmed it for you. It draws the squares making use of a nested for loop.

Here is the code:

```py
import turtle
def draw_square(t, sz):
    """Get turtle t to draw a square with sz side"""
    for i in range(5):
        for i in range(4):
            t.forward(sz)
            t.left(90)
        t.penup()
        t.forward(sz + (sz))
        t.pendown()

def main():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor("white")

    alex = turtle.Turtle()
    alex.color("Blue")

    draw_square(alex, 20)

    wn.exitonclick()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is the output: [image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if you wish you can use the `fill()` function to fill the squares. I thought I would leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I implemented it.

```
import turtle
    
    def draw_Square():
        '''Draws a square'''
        tess = turtle.Turtle()
        tess.color("red")
        window = turtle.Screen()
        window.bgcolor("lightgreen")
        window.title("Some random title")
        #The first iteration  does each square while the inner one works each size of the square.
        for squares in range(5):
                for sides in range(4):
                            tess.forward(20)
                            tess.left(90)
                tess.penup()
                tess.forward(20 + 20)
     #Increments at each iteration from the current position
                tess.pendown()
    
        window.mainloop()
    
draw_Square()#Function call
```